# Вернуть тип объекта

Tags: c#, vknet

Как в переменную, записать тип объекта и потом её использовать? Например, есть тип `VkNet.Enums.SafetyEnums.PhotoAlbumType.Wall` его нужно записать. Просто у меня `comboBox`, в нем 3 строки и исходя из выбранной строки (по индексу) нужно вернуть нужный тип.

Типа такого:

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        fff = VkNet.Enums.SafetyEnums.PhotoAlbumType.Wall;
        break;
    case 1:
        fff = VkNet.Enums.SafetyEnums.PhotoAlbumType.Profile;
        break;
    case 2:
        fff = VkNet.Enums.SafetyEnums.PhotoAlbumType.Saved;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то тебе нужно [ComboBox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx).

Приводишь его к нужному типу и анализируешь.

Но это при условии, что у тебя в DataSource нужный объект, а не просто текст, как например:

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Cnt { get; set; }
}


  listProd = new List<Product>();
        listProd.Add(new Product() { id = 2, Name = "Прод 2", Cnt = 2 });
        listProd.Add(new Product() { id = 3, Name = "Прод 3", Cnt = 4 });
        comboBox1.DataSource = listProd;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Тогда, как я сказал, можно будет продеать такую штуку:

```
var selVal = (Product) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: `ComboBox.SelectedItem` возвращает ведь выбранную строку в `comboBox`, как моя проблема связана с этим? Или я вас неправильно понял, приведите, пожалуйста, пример если не затруднит :)

Comment: @Максим, а что у тебя в самом ComboBox содержится? Просто строка? Не какой-нибудь словарь?

Comment: А, я понял ход ваших мыслей, но нет, у меня в `ComboBox` свой текст.

Comment: @Максим, сделать словарь <Текст,Тип> нельзя в вашей задаче и привязать его к ComboBox? Тогда бы вы могли бы получить по индексу тип, который относится к выбранному типу.

Comment: А как это сделать? Что-то разобраться не могу.

Comment: @Максим, добавил пример

Comment: Спасибо, вечером попробую, о результатах отпишусь.

Comment: Нет, ваш вариант мне не подходит(